# TinyMCE When I click on the "Insert Link" button I get Uncaught TypeError: n is undefined

Tags: tinymce-6

On 6.4.2 - 2023-04-26.  Is this a known bug and I just have to upgrade to a newer version? Or am I configuring TinyMCE incorrectly.  This issue did not happen with previous versions of TinyMCE.

```
Uncaught TypeError: n is undefined @ plugin.min.js: 9:454
    g https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
    Sn https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
    En https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
    Un https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
    qn https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
    buttonBehaviours https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    wy https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    buttonBehaviours https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    run https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    L https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    run https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    r https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    k https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Lw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    fold https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Lw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Pw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Uw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    triggerEvent https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Si https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Si https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    triggerEvent https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Vs https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Fs https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Rs https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    e https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    r https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    k https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Lw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    fold https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Lw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Pw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Uw https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    triggerEvent https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    triggerEvent https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Si https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    Si https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    triggerEvent https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    r https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
    s https://www.jamescobban.net/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
```

Answer (score 0):

At version 6.8.2 the insert link button works.